# Getting an error while trying to create an order using Rest API magento 2

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am trying to create an order using REST API in magento 2. This is the link that I am following for the process

```
https://github.com/acolono/php-magento-api-sandbox
```

I have created the files on my magento root folder and trying to create an order, but I am getting an error regarding shipment. This is the error

```
{"message":"Carrier with such method not found : %1, %2","parameters":["freeshipping_freeshipping","freeshipping_freeshipping"]}
```

I tried to locate this error message using grep command and found the file from where it is coming. The error is coming from following file

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/ShippingInformationManagement.php
```

This is the code in the above file that gives the error

```
if (!$quote->getIsVirtual()
        && !$shippingAddress->getShippingRateByCode($shippingAddress->getShippingMethod())
    ) {
        $errorMessage = $methodCode ?
            __('Carrier with such method not found: %1, %2', $carrierCode, $methodCode)
            : __('The shipping method is missing. Select the shipping method and try again.');
        throw new NoSuchEntityException(
            $errorMessage
        );
    }
```

I separated the if conditions into 2 if and tried to find which one is giving the error. Above code was updated to this

```
if (!$quote->getIsVirtual())
    {
        $errorMessage = $methodCode ?
            __('Carrier with such method not found: %1, %2', $carrierCode, $methodCode)
            : __('The shipping method is missing. Select the shipping method and try again.');
        throw new NoSuchEntityException(
            $errorMessage
        );
    }
    
    if (!$shippingAddress->getShippingRateByCode($shippingAddress->getShippingMethod())
    ) {
        $errorMessage = $methodCode ?
            __('Carrier with such method not found: %1, %2', $carrierCode, $methodCode)
            : __('The shipping method is missing. Select the shipping method and try again.');
        throw new NoSuchEntityException(
            $errorMessage
        );
    }
```

I found out that this if condition **if(!$quote->getIsVirtual())** is giving the error. But I am not sure what this if condition is checking and why I am getting this error. Could someone guide me in the right direction.

This is my REST API code to create the order. I am using 2 files as mentioned above. This is the doc that I am following.

```
https://github.com/acolono/php-magento-api-sandbox
```

I have created 2 files on magento root.

First - api.php with following content

```
<?php
class MagentoClient {
  public $bearer_token = '';
  public $base_url = '';

  public function __construct($token, $base_url) {
    $this->base_url = $base_url;
    $this->bearer_token = $token;
  }

  public function request($endpoint, $method = 'GET', $body = FALSE) {

    // Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->base_url . $endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer " . $this->bearer_token;
    if ($body) {
      $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
      echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close ($ch);
    return $result;
  }

  public function getProduct($product_id) {
    return $this->request('/products/' . $product_id . '/', 'GET');
  }

  public function createCart() {
    return $this->request('/guest-carts/', 'POST');
  }

  public function addToCart($cart_id, $product_sku, $quantity = 1) {
    $order = array(
        'cartItem' => array(
        'quote_id' => $cart_id,
        'sku' => $product_sku,
        'qty' => $quantity,
      )
    );
    return $this->request('/guest-carts/' . $cart_id . '/items',
      'POST',
      json_encode($order)
    );
  }

  public function setShipping($cart_id, $shipping) {
    return $this->request('/guest-carts/' . $cart_id . '/shipping-information',
      'POST',
      json_encode($shipping)
    );
  }

  public function placeOrder($cart_id, $payment_method = 'cashondelivery') {
    $payment = array(
      'paymentMethod' => array('method' => $payment_method)
    );

    return $this->request('/guest-carts/' . $cart_id . '/order',
      'PUT',
      json_encode($payment)
    );
  }

  public function getPaymentMethods($cart_id) {
    return $this->request('/guest-carts/' . $cart_id . '/payment-information', 'GET');
  }

}
```

2 file is place_order.php with the following content

```
<?php
$userData = array("username" => "****", "password" => "********");
$ch = curl_init("https://staging.nonnon.co.uk/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

$token = curl_exec($ch);

require_once 'api.php';

// $orderData_dynamic = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);

// The URL to your Magento 2 instance (ending with /index.php/rest/V1)
$api_url = 'https://staging.nonnon.co.uk/index.php/rest/V1';

// Fill in the SKU of the product which should be ordered.
$sku = 'test next product2';

$magento = new MagentoClient($token, $api_url);

$product = $magento->getProduct($sku);

$cart = $magento->createCart();
$cart = str_replace('"', '', $cart);

$order_filled = $magento->addToCart($cart, $sku, 1);
//var_dump($order_filled);

$ship_to = array (
  'addressInformation' =>
    array (
      'shipping_address' =>[
        'firstname'    => 'Jodie', //address Details
        'lastname'     => 'Livingstone',
        'street' => [
            0 => '101 princess street'
        ],
        'city' => 'South Yorkshire',
        'country_id' => 'GB',
        'postcode' => 'Dn67lt',
        'telephone' => '07849175850 ',
        'save_in_address_book' => 0
    ],
      'billing_address' =>[
        'firstname'    => 'Jodie', //address Details
        'lastname'     => 'Livingstone',
        'street' => [
            0 => '101 princess street'
        ],
        'city' => 'South Yorkshire',
        'country_id' => 'GB',
        'postcode' => 'Dn67lt',
        'telephone' => '07849175850 ',
        'save_in_address_book' => 0
    ],
      'shipping_method_code' => 'freeshipping_freeshipping',
      'shipping_carrier_code' => 'freeshipping_freeshipping',
    ),
);

$order_shipment = $magento->setShipping($cart, $ship_to);
echo "<pre>";print_r($order_shipment);die('tttt');


//$payment = $magento->getPaymentMethods($cart);
//var_dump($payment);

$ordered = $magento->placeOrder($cart, 'nextpayment');
//echo "\nordered:\n";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($ordered);
```

?>

This is the line in the above file where I see the error.

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($order_shipment);die('tttt');
```

I am quoting the error again here.

```
{"message":"Carrier with such method not found testing top: %1, %2","parameters":["freeshipping_freeshipping","freeshipping_freeshipping"]}
```

I have checked freeshipping_freeshipping method is enabled for my store.

[image]

Some details regarding my website, that could be the reason for the error,

We have 4 website and store, and the product that is used in the api is assigned to all the stores. Plz someone could help me to proceed further as I am stuck in this error.

[image]

Comment: the product you're trying to add to cart is virtual/configurable/simple... ? Magento creates a Virtual Quote when all the products of the quote are virtual (as you said seems the condition you're stuck with), and as i know there's no shipping method for virtual orders

Comment: I just checked it to confirm, it is a simple product